# Creating frame buffer object with no color attachment

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

I know that we can create such a FBO (no color attachment, just a depth attachment) e.g this can be used for shadow mapping.

Also, the FBO completeness check states that

- Each draw buffers must either specify color attachment points that
  have images attached or must be GL_NONE​.
  (GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER​ when false). Note that this
  test is not performed if OpenGL 4.2 or ARB_ES2_compatibility is
  available.

My question is, is it necessary to explicitly mention this by using

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

If I dont specify any color attachments, is it not understood by OpenGL that it will not have any color buffers attached?
(My Program just worked fine on OpenGL 4.0 without mentioning "glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);" so I assume its okay not to, but wiki says FB completeness check must have failed)

Answer (score 1):

In my application, using a depth buffer for shadow mapping, NOT calling

```
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

does NOT result in an incomplete framebuffer if this framebuffer has no color attachments.

However, everything does turn into crap and the depth texture is apparently either not writeable or readable or both.

Why this is so, and whether this is universally so I will leave in the middle. I am just informing you of my findings, and my findings indicate you should be cautious with omitting this statement.